# Strange behavior in a codeigniter library

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've made an incredibly basic library, with a single function to check if the user is logged in now or not.

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed'); 

class Lib {

    public function is_logged_in()
    {
        $CI =& get_instance();
        if($CI->session->userdata('uid') === FALSE)
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
        else
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
}

/* End of file Lib.php */
```

If I call the function from a controller, the code is definitely run and when not logged in it makes it into the `if` statement. I can add an echo to test that the code is definitely executed, but never is anything returned. If I change the return to a number, nothing is returned. If I change the return to a string, then and only then is stuff actually returned. I'm calling the function like `$this->lib->is_logged_in()`, and have added the library to the autoload.php file.

The return is definitely executed as the function is exited. error reporting is set to `E_ALL`. Why in the heck won't this work?

(also yes I do realize the function isn't complete and secure yet.)

Comment: How are you determining that the return is executed?

Comment: Try printing your return in `var_dump()`

Comment: @NullUserException: The code block exits. I can echo prior to either `return` and it will run, I can echo after either and it will not.

Comment: It's there, so why can't I echo it?

Comment: I agree with @ace; `var_dump()` a call to the function. Your code as written is fine.

Comment: `var_dump()` reveals that false is indeed being returned, why can't I simply echo it?

Comment: @Cyclone Booleans don't produce any output when echo'd

Comment: @NullUserException True seems to print 1, so that's inaccurate

Comment: @Cyclone Hmmm, you are right. I thought you'd have to cast it to int for it to do that... But anyway, if you cast false to int (ie: `echo (int) FALSE` you'll get 0.

Comment: And for the record, I think booleans in PHP are a huge mess, especially because other types get arbitrarily converted into booleans when used in a boolean context.

Comment: @NullUserException: Looks like PHP stands for "Probably Hates Programmers" in this case then :/

Comment: @NullUserException: Booleans in PHP are not a huge mess. Programmers that don't know how to use PHP booleans (or C++ booleans, or Java booleans for that matter) are those who make the mess. PHP types (including type juggling) are [very well documented](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.php). It's not the language's fault if the coder can't read properly.

Comment: @netcoder I disagree. If I create a language where 0 is true and 1 is false that's OK if I document it?

Comment: I'm not very experienced with operators but `===` also checks if two values are the same type but you are not comparing to anything. Have you tried `==` ?

Comment: @Cyberjunkie Nope, `===` is actually the "identical" operator, ie: it will check if they are the same type AND have the same value. Type juggling is the reason why such an operator came into existence.

Comment: @netcoder And why did you bring up Java and C++? In Java and C++ you can't compare booleans with strings, or ints for that matter - with the exception of 0 == false and 1 == true in C++ (and everything else failing, like a sane person would expect, instead of 13 == true like in PHP).

Comment: @netcoder In fact, I can't think of any language where `13 == true` would be true. Even dynamically typed languages like Python, although allowing such a comparison, will return False. The `==` operator should behave like the `===` does.

Comment: Btw guys, I'd like to point out that in vb.net, `True` is actually equal to -1. See the second item on the list http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic#Characteristics

Comment: @NullUserException: Don't get emotional, what's your point with that rant anyway? My point is, the behavior is well documented so if you can't use a language feature properly, it's not the language's fault, but the programmer's fault. Besides, `13` evaluates to true in C++, JavaScript, Perl and Python, to name a few. The difference is that in PHP you can explicitly tell `(13 == true)` because of the way it juggles types, while in others you just do `(13)`. But at the end of the day, `13` still evaluates to true, no matter how it's written. If you don't like it, then just use `13 === true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How are you determining that the return is executed? – NullUserException
>
> @NullUserException: The code block exits. I can echo prior to either return and it will run, I can echo after either and it will not. – Cyclone

If you are trying to `echo` something *after* the `return` in your function, it will not work by design, I think this is probably universal to all languages. Anything after the `return` will not be executed. It will be parsed, but not executed.

`var_dump($this->lib->is_logged_in())` should give you `bool(true)` or `bool(false)`, or a "Trying to get property of non-object" error if `lib` is not loaded correctly.

Unless there is something you aren't sharing with us, the function should work as expected.

If you're still in doubt, assign the return value to a variable, then `var_dump()` the variable before you `return` it. Should be the same result.

**EDIT**: Sorry, I missed this in the long stream of comments:

> var_dump() reveals that false is indeed being returned, why can't I simply echo it

I don't believe that echo'ing `FALSE` should give you any [output](http://codepad.org/057tnszG), but echoing `TRUE` should give you `1`.

This also has nothing to do specifically with Codeigniter.

For all practical purposes, there's no good reason to `echo` the return value of this function, or really anything where you expect a boolean return value. If it is returning the value you expect, then it is working.